# Wail until iframe contents finish reloading

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events, reload

I have an `<iframe>` with content designed (and allowed) to be modified by JS code.
At some point I want to clear iframe's content (i.e. load its HTML from the document pointed by `src` attribute) and start operating on a new DOM as soon as it's loaded.

It seems very convenient to use the `iframe.contentWindow.location.reload()` function. It reloads the entire inner document and replaces `iframe.contentWindow` and `iframe.contentDocument` objects with new ones.

The problem is I can't listen to `DOMContentLoaded` event on a newly created document. If I add a listener to `iframe.contentDocument` right after calling `reload()`, it seems to attach to the old document object which is about to be destroyed. If I wait for some time before adding listener, I have a chance to set it after the event has fired and miss it.
Observing the `readyState` property of the document doesn't help because it can be set to `"complete"` when the document hasn't reloaded yet as well as when it has reloaded and finished loading its content.

The best solution I could come up with as far is quite ugly and requires active polling:

```js
function reloadIframe(iframe) {
    iframe.contentWindow.dirty = true;
    iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
}

function documentReady(iframe) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (
                !iframe.contentWindow.dirty &&  // check that this is not the old window instance
                iframe.contentDocument.readyState != "loading"
            ) {
                resolve();
            }
        }, CHECK_READY_INTERVAL);
    });
}
```

Is the a simpler way to get notified when a window has finished reloading?

**Note:** I am able to remove an `<iframe>` element itself and create the new one, but this approach had even more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Due to cross-origin limitations, this will only work assuming you are running the source and parent frames from the same domain, however, you should be able to use:

```
function documentReady(iframe) {
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    if ( doc.readyState  == 'complete' ) {
        iframe.contentWindow.onload = function() {
            return true;
        };
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will essentially get the iframe document and check whether the document and all sub-resources have finished loading. If they have, it will then call onload to verify that it has finished loading. The function will return true or false depending on whether the iframe has successfully loaded. If wanted, you could also run the function in a loop after requesting the iframe to reload, until the iframe has completed loading.

Comment: This code has the same problem - you need to actively run it in a loop to find the moment when the document becomes ready. What I want is an asynchronous solution to get notified only once at the right moment.
Moreover, there is a chance that you call the `documentReady` function only after the document was loaded and miss the `onload` event